# How to display the string with HTML ASCII code?

Tags: html, ascii

I have a string "akl&#85@^" as a password retrieved from database.  The string is showing a different value as "aklU@^" on the web page.

It is basically because "&#85" is the HTML ASCII code of the upper case letter "U".

Is there anyway I can skip the convertion, and display the string as "akl&#85@^"? Thanks.

Not sure if it matters, I'm coding in C#.

Comment: Which language you are using and can you show your code?

Comment: String.fromCharCode(n1, n2, ..., nX) use this function, in java script

Comment: You really shouldn't display your users' passwords.

Comment: You shouldn't even know your users' passwords. http://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs

Comment: HTML has nothing to do with ASCII. It uses Unicode, as in [&#128690;](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F6B2/index.htm)

Comment: Which web page rendering technology are you using? Razor? Webforms? Roll-your-own? Your code seems vulnerable to HTML/script-injection (or just plain misformatting) if you are pasting data strings into HTML code. Your question is an attempt to address it but be sure to do it systematically. Every HTML text node is HTML, not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know C# but basically I believe you should do a replace operation of the password string, replacing `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: I ended up doing a stringvalue.replace('&', '&amp') in some javascript that was being used to get this value and that got it to display correctly.  Nice and simple!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function to escape HTML

```
function escapeHTML(str){
    return str.replace( /[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function( i) { return '&#' + i .charCodeAt(0) + ';'; });
}
```

```html
<span id="testResult"></span>
<script>
function escapeHTML(str){
        return str.replace( /[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function( i) { return '&#' + i .charCodeAt(0) + ';'; });
    }
document.getElementById("testResult").innerHTML = escapeHTML("akl&#85@^");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function unicodeEscape(str) {
  for (var result = '', index = 0, charCode; !isNaN(charCode = str.charCodeAt(index++));) {
    result += '\\u' + ('0000' + charCode.toString(16)).slice(-4);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Or you can use this**

```
function escapeUnicode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^\0-~]/g, function(ch) {
        return "\\u" + ("000" + ch.charCodeAt().toString(16)).slice(-4);
    });
}
```

You can use this to skip all of your unicode ascii, this is not created by me just found this which will work for you.